# Problem with a basic lemma in Lambda Calculus

Tags: logic, computer-science, lambda-calculus

I have some serious problems with Lambda Calculus. In an [introduction by Barendregt and Barendsen](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf) at page 11 there is the following lemma, whose proof I do not completely get.

> $\mathbf{\lambda} \vdash ( \lambda x_1 \dots x_n . M) X_1\dots X_n = M [ x_1 := X_1] \dots [x_n := X_n]$.

Even if I find the result intuitive, the proof, which should be obvious by induction and $\beta$-reduction, is not clear. In particular, I really don't get ***why the order is preserved in the manipulation***, that is, from LHS we get on the RHS that  $x_1 := X_1$,
$x_2 := X_2$, etc (and I think here the order has to be important). I have the feeling that this is the symptom of a deep misunderstanding of how lambda calculus works in general.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(\lambda x_1 x_2. M)X_1 X_2$ is actually shorthand for the following:

$$((\lambda x_1 . (\lambda x_2 . M)) X_1 ) X_2$$

Considering the second $\lambda$-term as being opaque - say it's $Q$ - that is $((\lambda x_1 . Q) X_1 ) X_2$, which is just $(Q[x_1 := X_1])X_2$ by $\beta$-reduction.

Now substitute back $Q = \lambda x_2 . M$, so we have $$((\lambda x_2 . M)[x_1 := X_1]) X_2$$

Since $x_1$ does not appear in the phrase "$\lambda x_2$", we can move the substitution inside the $\lambda$-term: $$(\lambda x_2 . M[x_1 := X_1]) X_2$$

And now we are in a position to use induction: we've shown that $$(\lambda x_1 x_2 .M)X_1 X_2 = (\lambda x_2 . M[x_1 := X_2])X_2$$
and we can just keep going in the same way.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pay attention that $(\lambda x_2.M)[x_1 := X_1] \equiv \lambda x_2.M[x_1 := X_1]$ holds not only because $x_1$ does not appear in the phrase "$\lambda x_2$", but also (and most importantly) because $x_2$ is not a free variable in $X_1$ according to the variable convention (see my answer).

Comment: Indeed, I was rather hoping that the OP would accept your answer and not mine :)

Comment: I don't care about points. The important thing is to understand the reason why something works. :-)

Comment: LOL. Btw, I wanted to write to Taroccoesbrocco that the more I think about his answer the more I appreciate it, but still I really needed the actual manipulation. Thus, for example, his emphasis on the variable being free suddenly made me literally see what's going on that I never got about this mysterious $lambda$-calculus, e.g.,for something like $\lambda x. (\lambda x. x)2$, since in $M := \lambda x. x$ the variable $x$ is not free, and the expression stays the same (*I truly hope now I did not write something completely wrong!*). Thus, really thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: @PatrickStevens: I just came back to your answer and I was wondering about your statement that the original expression is a shorthand for $(\lambda x_1 . (\lambda x_2 . M)) X_1 X_2$. Just to be sure I see how it works step by step, shouldn't it actually be a shorthand of the even more cumbersome $((\lambda x_1 . (\lambda x_2 . M)) X_1 ) X_2 )$?

Comment: @Kolmin Yep, I did indeed miss out those brackets.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Ok, great! Maybe you could edit the answer for the learners that will come (if it is a problem, I will do it for you).

Answer (score 4):

There is an implicit but fundamental hypothesis in the lemma you cited: the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are not free in $X_1, \dots, X_n$. This is the reason why the order of the substitutions in $M[x_1:=X_1]\dots[x_n :=X_n]$ actually does not matter.

This hypothesis is implicit in the definition of $\beta$-conversion, because you always assume the *variable convention* 2.6 (p. 10):

> If $M_1, \dots, M_n$ occur in a certain mathematical context (e.g.
>   definition, proof), then in these terms all bound variables
>   are chosen to be different from the free  variables.

Note that this variable convention is also crucial in the definition of substitution for abstractions (p. 10). Indeed, setting
$$(\lambda y.M)[x := N] \equiv \lambda y. M[x := N]$$
is correct only in the case $y$ is not a free variable in $N$; this condition can always be fulfilled by renaming bound variables ($\lambda$-terms are considered up to $\alpha$-conversion, i.e. up to renaming of bound variables).
If the variable convention were not fulfilled you would have for instance 
$$(\lambda y. x)[x := y] \equiv \lambda y.y\,,$$
which is clearly wrong, instead of the correct
$$(\lambda y. x)[x := y] \equiv \lambda z.y\,.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think I need some time to digest it, since it is slightly more abstract that what I was looking for. But still, thanks a lot!

Comment: Concerning your comment below Patrick Stevens' answer, I see what you mean (I think that Patrick Stevens was assuming it as well as I was).

Comment: Not sure you could see it, but I just wrote now below Patrick Stevens' answer a comment where I try to express how helpful your answer is (I am literally understanding, maybe the obvious, but still something I did not understand before).