# Lambda-calculus - Basic Problem with application of Fixedpoint theorem

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

This question is a sort of follow-up of a [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674924/problem-with-a-basic-lemma-in-lambda-calculus). Again, I just do not really see how the $\lambda$-calculus actually works. Now, the problem is with **Example 2.13** at page 12 of [Introduction to Lambda Calculus](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf).

The authors write (I write the conditionals in the inverse order):

> $\exists G \ \forall X \ GX= \mathbf{S}GX$. Indeed,
>
> $$\begin{align}
> G \equiv \mathbf{Y} ( \lambda gx.\mathbf{S}gx) & \overset{?}{\Rightarrow} G = ( \lambda gx.\mathbf{S}gx)G\\
> & \Rightarrow G =  \lambda x.\mathbf{S}Gx\\
> & \overset{?}{\Rightarrow} Gx =  \mathbf{S}Gx\\
> & \Rightarrow GX =  {S}GX.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> where $\mathbf{Y} \equiv \lambda f.(\lambda x. f(xx)) (\lambda x. f(xx))$ and $\mathbf{S} \equiv \lambda xyz. xz(yz)$.

I think the last conditional comes form the fact that $x$ is arbitrary. Still, the question marks point out the steps that are really mysterious for me.

Also, the authors close the example by writing that the same result is obtained with $G \equiv \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{S}$. I simply have no idea how to manipulate this object.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may want to leverage the fact, proved immediately before, that $\forall F.\mathbf{Y}F=F(\mathbf{Y}F)$.

Comment: Note that your definition of ${\bf Y}$ is wrong (there should be just one occurrence of $\lambda f$). I fixed it.

Comment: @DerekElkins Unfortunately, part of the problem is that I see it, but I don't see how to use it.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks a lot (copy and paste side-effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as stated in Theorem 2.12 of your [notes](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf), ${\bf Y}F = F({\bf Y}F)$ for any term $F$. Therefore, 
\begin{align}
 G \equiv {\bf Y} (\lambda gx.{\bf S} gx) =  (\lambda gx.{\bf S} gx)({\bf Y} (\lambda gx.{\bf S} gx)) \equiv (\lambda gx.{\bf S} gx)G
\end{align}
This explains the first step you marked. Concerning the second step you marked, from $G = \lambda x.{\bf S} Gx$, by applying the $\beta$-rule (Definition 2.7 in your [notes](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf)) and the first compatibility rule (Definition 2.7 in your [notes](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf)), it follows that
\begin{align}
  Gx =  (\lambda x.{\bf S} Gx)x = ({\bf S} Gx)[x := x] \equiv {\bf S} Gx.
\end{align}

Finally, I show that even when you set $G \equiv {\bf YS}$, you get that $GX= \mathbf{S}GX$ for any term $X$. As above, by Theorem 2.12,
\begin{align}
G \equiv {\bf YS} = {\bf S}({\bf YS}) \equiv {\bf S} G
\end{align}
and so $GX = {\bf S}GX$ for any term $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really a great answer. One question: my problem with $Gx = (\lambda x. \mathbf{S}Gx)x$ actually lies in what you call an application of the $\beta$ rule along with $G = \lambda x. \mathbf{S}Gx$. I really don't see this point.

Comment: @Kolmin - Do you understand why $G = \lambda x. {\bf S}Gx$?

Comment: Yep, that's fine. It's just that I don't know how to see the $x$ on the LHS and the RHS in this context in the problematic expression (say that it's like  I am not sure if it is like in 'standard' math and we can 'multiply' both sides or there is something else I don't know that allows to get there from $G = \lambda x. \mathbf{S} Gx$).

Comment: @Kolmin If you had to rigorously *prove* that "multiplying both sides of an equation by a value" was valid in algebra, how would you do it?

Comment: @Kolmin - Since we have proved that $G = \lambda x. {\bf S}Gx$, then by the first compatibility rule (Def. 2.7) we have that $Gx = (\lambda x. {\bf S}Gx)x$.

Comment: @Kolmin - Moreover, in general, when you have a term of the form $(\lambda x.M)N$, the $\beta$-rule (Def. 2.7) says that this term is "the same as" $M[x:=N]$, where the latter is the term obtained from $M$ by substitution $N$ for all the free occurrences of $x$ in $M$. For instance, $  (\lambda x.{\bf S} Gx)x = ({\bf S} Gx)[x := x] \equiv {\bf S} Gx$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Gosh...compatibility rules (!)... Thanks a lot, really!